# Positioning problems with canvas images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a `Canvas` project, trying to do it with a `background image` and a smaller one over it. Then I'll continue with doing some interactiveness on it.
 But my current problem is that when I draw the `background` and the `image` on setup, the positioning of the 2nd `image` is right where I put it.
But when I try to do the second `image` as an `object` and construct it on its `function`, the `image` it's being drawed on origin `(0, 0)`, ignoring the parameters.
Here are both codes.

**On Same Setup:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var maquina;

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{

  //Resizing
  canvas.style.width = '100%';
  canvas.style.height = '100vh';
  canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

  if(canvas.getContext){
    setup(canvas, ctx);
  }

});

function setup(canvas, ctx){
  //Pinto de verde el fondo del canvas
  var background = new Image();
  background.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/P9QTw6r/background.png';  
  background.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
  }

  //Obtengo las coordenadas del centro del canvas
  centerX = canvas.width/2;
  centerY = canvas.height/2;
  
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/tYwLtpB/maquina.png';
  img.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(img, centerX-10, canvas.height-100);
  }  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Monitor</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**On its function:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var maquina;

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{

  //Resizing
  canvas.style.width = '100%';
  canvas.style.height = '100vh';
  canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

  if(canvas.getContext){
    setup(canvas, ctx);
  }

});

function setup(canvas, ctx){
  //Pinto de verde el fondo del canvas
  var background = new Image();
  background.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/P9QTw6r/background.png';  
  background.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
  }

  //Obtengo las coordenadas del centro del canvas
  centerX = canvas.width/2;
  centerY = canvas.height/2;

  maquina = new maquina(centerX-10, canvas.height-100);

}

function maquina(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/tYwLtpB/maquina.png';
  img.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y);
  }
  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Monitor</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is within your maquina() function.  Just use the passed-parameters x and y directly.  I dont't think you need to set this.x = x and this.y = y.

```
function maquina(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/tYwLtpB/maquina.png';
  img.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y);
  }
}
```

Try

```
function maquina(x, y){
  //this.x = x;
  //this.y = y;

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/tYwLtpB/maquina.png';
  img.onload = function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  }

}
```

Comment: I did it that way because after if I wanna see the current position of it, I could check it by those parameters, in a Object way. (maquina.x or maquina.y).. How can I do it that way?

Comment: Haha I figured out the problem, "this" was the image, I needed to do ctx.drawImage(img, maquina.x, maquina.y) for this to work. Thanks you kind of inspired me.

Comment: Sure, no problem, glad to hear it!